# How to rank salesman changing in the time on a contract

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

i'm a beginner on sql, and i hope my post will be clear.

So i have 1 table (see pictures) with my SalesMen linked to a contract.
And i want to be able to rank each SalesMen on a contract.
So if today on a contract 001 i have Martin as the only SalesMan he should have '1' as rank.
But if one day Martin is fired and the new guy is Frank. Then Martin will be rank 2 and Frank '1'.

example:

```
idContract    idSalesMan    DateLoad
001           Jean          1900-01-01
001           Jean          1900-02-02
001           Jean          1900-03-03
002            Martin       1900-01-01
002            Martin       1900-02-02
002            Frank        1900-03-03
```

The result i want :

```
idContract    idSalesMan    DateLoad       RankedSalesMan
001           Jean          1900-01-01     1
001           Jean          1900-02-02     1
001           Jean          1900-03-03     1
002            Martin       1900-01-01     2
002            Martin       1900-02-02     2
002            Frank        1900-03-03     1
```

What i did:
1st try : 
`select idContract,IdSalesMan,
Row_number() over (partition by IDContract , IDsALESmAN order by IDsALESmAN )`
But it gave me a regular 1,2,3,4

Then i tried

```
select
x.*
,case when x.PrecedingSalesMan = x.SalesMan then
Row_number() over (partition by IDContract , IDsALESmAN order by IDsALESmAN ) 
from(

select idContract,IdSalesMan,

,LAG(CodeAgent,1) over (order by NoContract, idCustomers, kCode_Agent) as PrecedingSalesMan) x
```

But it doesn't work neither :(

I don,t know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you just need dense_rank()

```
select *,dense_rank()over(partition by idContract order by idSalesMan) as rn
from table_name
```

Comment: Yes it worked with a partition by IdContract instead of idSalesMan. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `DENSE_RANK()` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.idContract ORDER BY t.idSalesMan) AS RankedSalesMan
FROM table t;
```

You need only `idContract` in partition clause.